# Registering Bundle ID on Developer Portal after App Transfer

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am planning an App Transfer in ITunes Connect and have the following questions:

After an App Transfer if I want to publish new version of the app with the same bundle ID (App ID) as in the previous organization, how can I register this bundle ID in the new organization's Developer Portal?

Is the Bundle Id (App ID) created automatically in the new organization's Developer Portal after the transfer?

I have reviewed Apple Documentation but could not find an exact answer to the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , your Bundle Id will be re-created in the new organization's Developer Portal